# Applying Cauchy’s mean value theorem twice in a row

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, functions, derivatives

exercise:

Let $f$ be twice differentiable in an interval $A$. Show that for every distinct pair of points $a$ and $x$ in $A$ there is a point $\xi$, strictly between $a$ and $x$, such that
$$
f(x)-f(a)-f^{\prime}(a)(x-a)=\frac{1}{2} f^{\prime \prime}(\xi)(x-a)^{2}
$$
Hint. Apply Cauchy's mean value theorem twice in a row to the quotient
$$
\frac{f(x)-f(a)-f^{\prime}(a)(x-a)}{(x-a)^{2}}
$$

My attempt:

By MVT we know that there is a point  $c$ strictly between $a$ and $x$ such that
$$1)\frac{f(x)-f(a)}{x-a}=f^{\prime}(c)$$ from this we get $$ 2)f(x)-f(a)=f^{\prime}(c)(x-a)$$ and substituting it in the quotiont above we obtain $$\frac{f^{\prime}(c)(x-a)-f^{\prime}(a)(x-a)}{(x-a)^{2}}=\frac{f^{\prime}(c)-f^{\prime}(a)}{x-a}
$$ and again applying Cauchy's mean value theorem we have a point $\xi$, strictly between $a$ and $c$, such that $$\frac{f^{\prime}(c)-f^{\prime}(a)}{x-a}=f^{\prime\prime}(\xi)$$ which is $$f^{\prime}(c)=f^{\prime}(a)+f^{\prime\prime}(\xi)(x-a)$$ and considering this in 2) we have $$
f(x)-f(a)-f^{\prime}(a)(x-a)=f^{\prime \prime}(\xi)(x-a)^{2}
$$

MY question: why I lost the fraction $\frac{1}{2}$, what is wrong with this proof??

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$$\frac{f^{\prime}(c)-f^{\prime}(a)}{x-a}=f^{\prime\prime}(\xi)$$  is not correct. You need $$\frac{f^{\prime}(c)-f^{\prime}(a)}{c-a}$$
to apply MVT.

Comment: oh thanks I missed this

Answer (score 0):

I found satisfying function for MVT

$$\frac{f(x)-f(a)-f^{\prime}(a)(x-a)}{(x-a)^{2}}=\frac{f(x)-f^{\prime}(a)x-f(x)+f^{\prime}(a)a}{(x-a)^2}$$

let $$g(t)=f(t)-f^{\prime}(a)t$$ and $$h(t)=(t-a)^2$$ so by twice application of Cauchy's MVT there is a point $c$ between $x$ and $a$, and $\xi$ between $c$ and $a$ such that
$$\frac{g(x)-g(a)}{h(x)-h(a)}=\frac{f(x)-f^{\prime}(a)x-f(x)+f^{\prime}(a)a}{(x-a)^2}=\frac{f^{\prime}(c)-f^{\prime}(a)}{2(c-a)}=\frac{1}{2}f^{\prime\prime}(\xi)$$